# Prove that for a generalized circle $C$ and $z,w\notin C$, $z=w^*$ iff every cline $C_1$, $z,w\in C_1$, $C\bot C_1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that for a cline (a generalized circle) $C$ and $z,w\notin C$, $z=w^*$ iff every cline $C_1$, $z,w\in C_1$, $C\bot C_1$. **Hint**: show that it is enough to show this for the real line.

I tried firstly to show that using the real line, but I can't seem to understand orthogonality between the real line and a circle. I sense like the way I showed that $w=z^*$ assuming every cline $z,w\in C_1$ satisfies $C\bot C_1$ was way too reckless. What can I do? And how can I conclude that the following holds for every generalized circle?

Comment: What is a cline?

Comment: I was under the impression it stands for circle\line\circline, which is what a generalized circle is by definition. If it is not as popular as I thought it was, I shall edit.

Comment: Maybe it is well known, I just never heard the term.